# Valgrind “invalid write/read of size 1” errors memcpy

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

I know similar questions have been asked. However I still can't solve my problem. So I'd be really thankful if you could help me understand what I'm doing wrong. My program basically takes reads words from a File and puts them in a hashtable as key/value pairs. Then it compares words from another file to the ones in the HT and if found it gives the value back...

```
    char *str_dup(const char *s) {
      if (s == NULL) { // Optional test, s should point to a string
        return NULL;
      }
      size_t siz = strlen(s) + 1;
      char *y = malloc(sizeof(siz));
      if (y != NULL) {
        memcpy(y, s, siz);
      }
      return y;
    }

    int ht_put(HashTable *hashtable, const char *key, const char 
    *value){
    List *node;

    if (hashtable == NULL) {
            return 2;
    }

    node = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (node == NULL) {
            return 2;
    }
    node->key = str_dup(key);
    node->value = str_dup(value);

    node_handler(hashtable, node);

    return 0;
    }

    HashTable *dict;
    dict = ht_create(numKeys);
    if(dict == NULL){
        return 2;
    }

    char *val;
    int cnt = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer,1000000000,wb)) {
        // Eliminate UNIX/DOS line terminator
        val=strrchr(buffer,'\n');
        if (val) *val=0;
        val=strrchr(buffer,'\r');
        if (val) *val=0;

        //Find first occurrence of the separator ':'
        val=strchr(buffer,':');
        if (val) {
            // Truncates buffer string to first word
            // and (++) points second word
            *val++=0;
        }

        if (cnt<1000000000) {
            if (val!=NULL) {
                    if(ht_get(dict,buffer) == NULL){
                       ht_put(dict,buffer,val);
                    }
                    else {
                            ht_free(dict);
                            fclose(wb);
                            free(buffer);
                            fprintf(stderr,"Zwei Zeilen beschreiben 
         dasselbe deutsche Wort.\n");
                            exit(2);
                            return 2;
                    }
            }
            cnt++;
        } 
    }
    fclose(wb);
    free(buffer);
```

And here is what valgrind shows:

```
    ==478519== Invalid write of size 2
    ==478519==    at 0x4C325E3: memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in 
    /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==478519==    by 0x401701: strdup (loesung.c:62)
    ==478519==    by 0x401701: ht_put (loesung.c:285)
    ==478519==    by 0x400FA2: main (loesung.c:389)
    ==478519==  Address 0x51fc958 is 0 bytes after a block of size 
    8 alloc'd
    ==478519==    at 0x4C2E01F: malloc (in 
    /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==478519==    by 0x4016EA: strdup (loesung.c:60)
    ==478519==    by 0x4016EA: ht_put (loesung.c:285)
    ==478519==    by 0x400FA2: main (loesung.c:389)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are doing this:

`char *y = malloc(sizeof(siz));`

sizeof(size) equals the number of byte of the variable siz, which is the number of byte of size_t. Is this really what you want, or do you just want to do:

`char *y = malloc(siz);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it. It solved my problem and got to learn something.